How to make `HTMLAudioElement` download audio file in chunks?
I'm wanting the browser to reduce the amount of an audio file that is downloaded at a time.
I'm writing a custom music server with a rust backend. When the URL of an audio element is set, the browser requests the file. One of the request headers is range: bytes=0-. This indicates that the browser wants to download the entire file. This is problematic because some of these files are quite large (50+mb).
I've tried to return part of the file with an accompanying content-range header bytes=0-100000. The browser accepts it and starts playback, but then requests the next range of bytes=100000- immediately. I return the next set of data, and this process continues until the entire file is downloaded. I'm aware that the browser is requesting the entire file, but I don't know how to change that behavior.
I don't want to serve the entire file. It is likely that only a small part of a file will be played. How can I tell the browser to stop asking for data before it is needed? Ideally, the browser should request the first 30 seconds, then at 15 seconds request the next 30 seconds, and continue until the file is downloaded.
Edit: After further testing, it appears that Firefox will request all chunks, but Brave (chromium) does not. Brave still requests the entire file, but it stops making additional requests after several responses. Once some time has passed, it makes another set of responses. This is the behavior I want for all browsers.
This is my current rust implementation. The following code will return the range that is asked. If no ending range is specified, 5mb of data will be returned after the starting point unless the browser is firefox, in which case the entire file is returned.

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct RangeMiddleware {
    pub start: u64,
    pub end: Option<u64>
}

/**
 * 5 MB buffer
 */
const BUFFER_AMOUNT: usize = 5242880;

#[handler]
pub fn stream_file(
    Data(range): Data<&RangeMiddleware>,
    Data(track): Data<&TrackMiddleware>,
    header_map: &HeaderMap
) -> Result<impl IntoResponse, Error> {
    // Open the audio file
    if let Ok(mut file) = File::open(track.0.location.to_owned()) {
        let (mut buffer, content_range) = buffer_for_track_range(range, header_map, track);
        // Seek to the requested range
        if let Err(_) = file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(range.start)) {
            return Err(poem::Error::from_string("Can't seek", StatusCode::RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE));
        }

        if let Err(_) = file.read_exact(&mut buffer) {
            return Err(poem::Error::from_string("End of file.", StatusCode::RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE));
        };

        return Ok(Response::builder()
            .header(header::CONTENT_TYPE, guess_mime_type(&track.0.location))
            .header(header::CONTENT_RANGE, content_range)
            .status(StatusCode::PARTIAL_CONTENT)
            .body(buffer));
    } else {
        return Err(poem::Error::from_string("Failed to read file", StatusCode::NOT_FOUND));
    }
}

pub fn buffer_for_track_range(range: &RangeMiddleware, header_map: &HeaderMap, track: &TrackMiddleware) -> (Vec<u8>, String) {
    // If they have a range ending point, read to that point
    if let Some(end) = range.end {
        let buffer = vec![0; (end - range.start) as usize];
        let content_range = format!("bytes {}-{}/{}", range.start, end - 1, track.0.size);
        (buffer, content_range)
    } else {
        // No ending point...
        if let Some(agent) = header_map.get(USER_AGENT) {
            if agent.to_str().unwrap().contains("Firefox") {
                // Return the whole fire since firefox doesn't buffer
                let buffer = vec![0; track.0.size as usize - range.start as usize];
                let content_range = format!(
                    "bytes {}-{}/{}",
                    range.start, track.0.size - 1, track.0.size
                );

                return (buffer, content_range);
            }
        }

        // If the buffer is larger than the range, use the buffer
        if track.0.size as usize - range.start as usize > BUFFER_AMOUNT {
            (vec![0; BUFFER_AMOUNT], format!(
                "bytes {}-{}/{}",
                range.start, range.start as usize + BUFFER_AMOUNT, track.0.size)
            )
        } else {
            // The buffer is smaller than the remaining data, use remaining data
            (vec![0; track.0.size as usize - range.start as usize], format!(
                "bytes {}-{}/{}",
                range.start, track.0.size - 1, track.0.size)
            )
        }
    }
}



keywords:  Chunked downloading or resumable downloading.

@life888888 please consider elaborating.

@Mytho I misunderstood your question, so I gave the answer above. I want to rephrase your question: Using html5 audio, if the mp3 is 400 MB, how to tell the browser to only download 1 MB first, buffer it, and then just Do not download until the buffer is used up before sending another request to download.

@Mytho use MediaSource Extensions (MSE) in your html. Chrome support it. use mediaSource and  SourceBuffer

@Mytho MediaSource: addSourceBuffer() method
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/addSourceBuffer )

The rephrased question would be correct. I want to have the browser only download buffers when they are needed. I will look into MSE as a potential solution.

@Mytho  Firefox uses MSE and has weird error messages for audio/mpeg. But Chrome doesn't complain. Just a heads up.

It seems support for MSE varies per browser. There isn't a set of required formats so each browser only implements the ones they want. This is an issue since I have a variety of formats that I need to work. MSE also suggests the use of something like MPEG-DASH or HLS which would be more overhead. I'm considering using the HTTP-Range implementation I have now and checking the user-agent for firefox to respond with the entire file. Not want I want, but a temporary solution.
